# How should I effectively structure a redux state for these requirements?

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx

I have a complex web app state which needs to keep track of various things including currently selected items, id's of items to display, etc. The web app can also have multiple of these "States" with only 1 active at a time.

For example I have 3 "tabs", depending on the tab selected will determine which state to load all the properties from. So effectively I have 3 instances of the same state with different values stored.

How do I structure this? Currently I've done it as an array but it definitely doesn't seem effective as angular re-renders everything inside my state object any time I change a single thing.

Here's an example of the current state structure:

```
GlobalState {
    tabStates: TabState[]
    selectedTabId: number
}

TabState {
    tabId: number
    selectedItem: string
    otherSelectedItems: string[]
}
```

My tab state contains a fair bit more but I tried to simplify it.

Should I break each property inside the TabState out into its own state which for example for the selectedItem property would look something like this?

```
SelectedItemState {
    selectedItems: { [tabId: number]: string };
}
```

Any advice would be appreciated, please respond if my question isn't clear enough thank you.

**UPDATE 1**

MY selector is not returning the new value unless I spread the whole featureState. I only want to spread on the single property of the state and have the selector recognise this, what am I doing wrong?

I have the following state

```
appState: {
    feature1State: {
        tabIds: number[],
        selectedTabId: number,
        items: Item[], // Yes I will change this to entity pattern
        selectedItemId: {[tabId: number]: id}
    }
}
```

And my feature reducer for the feature1State:

```
UPDATE_SELECTED_ITEM: {
    feature1State.selectedItemId = { ...feature1State.selectedItemId };
    feature1State.selectedItemId[feature1State.selectedTabId] = action.payload.id;
    return feature1State;         
}
```

And the selectors

```
export const getFeature1State = createFeatureSelector<Feature1State> . 
('feature1State');

export const getSelectedIdForActiveTab = createSelector(
getFeature1State,
(state: Feature1State): number => 
state.selectedItemId[state.selectedTabId]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely best to avoid arrays for anything you want to modify.
If you need to keep things in order you can keep an array of id strings though.
(having said that in an app I work on we keep arrays of items as pages we want to display, but the items are just references to values in an object).

```
state: {
  tabStates: {
    [tabId]: {
      tabId: number
      selectedItemId: string
      otherSelectedItems: {
        [itemId]: string
      }
    },
    selectedTabId: number
  },
}
```

**UPDATE 1**

**I'm not familiar with using Angular with Redux or if there are differences to React

Your reducer should be a function that takes state and returns a new state object without mutating the existing state which your reducer is doing.

For the state shape I suggested (as I'm having trouble understanding the intricacies of yours) the reducer to update the selected tab's selected item would be

```
(tabStates, action) => {
  return {
    ...tabStates,
    [tabStates.selectedTabId]: {
      ...tabStates[tabStates.selectedTabId],
      selectedItemId: action.payload.id
    }
  }
}
```

(I modified my suggested state to include selectedTabId in tabStates)

This could be simplified by using immer which will do the same as above.

```
import produce from "immer";

(tabStates, action) => {
  return produce(tabStates, draft => {
    draft[tabStates.selectedTabId].selectedItemId = action.payload.id
  });
}
```

The process creates a new state object containing references to all of the properties of the original state and then replacing only the values that need to change with new objects/values.

For your selectors you should only need to use reselect where the selector does a lot of computations or where it uses `map` or `reduce` or similar which produce a new object every time which would cause a re-render, even if the values contained in the object have not changed.

In this case you can use a very simple selector as you are returning a value from state directly.

```
(state: TabStates): number => state[state.selectedTabId].selectedItemId);
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm having an issue where if I update any property on the tabState, then every selector subscribed to any property on the tabState is updating at the same time (because I clone the state into a new state object so change detection picks up my changes). My problem is I only want things subscribed to the particular property to update, is the only solution to this to separate it out into a separate root level state? Or is it possible I am not creating my selectors correctly?

Comment: You'd need to provide more code examples for selectors and reducers for us to be able to diagnose I think. "clone the state" sounds wrong though, you want to only be changing the data that needs changing (and the path to it) using the spread operator, or maybe immer if the changes are deep.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond lecstor. I updated my original post with more code, I know that I'm just not understanding how to use selectors correctly but I can't find on google a good example of what I want to do. I'm pretty sure because my selector is selecting the whole feature state, it will only detect a change when the whole feature state gets spread. Could you show me an example of how I should implement it?

Comment: I fixed it! I wasn't using the spread operator correctly in my reducer function. Your example made it clearer, thank you very much.